# pgbouncer bind(): Permission denied

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, pgbouncer

I have pgbouncer running locally with config:

```
[databases]
* = host=myremoteIP port=5432 user=postgres
listen_addr = *
listen_port = 6432
```

When I connect using pgsql using:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6432 -U postgres -W
```

I receive an error:

> psql: ERROR:  pgbouncer cannot connect to server

/var/log/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.log contains the following:

> WARNING Cannot listen on unix:/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.6432:
>   bind(): Permission denied

Disabling the firewall on the local and remote machines still results in the same error.

What configuration am I missing?

Comment: Checking your permission on `/var/run/postgresql/`.

Comment: @LuanHuynh it was 755. I've changed to 777 and now get: FATAL @src/system.c:113 in function change_file_mode(): chown(/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.6432, -1, 26) failed: Operation not permitted

Comment: Which Linux distro are you using? It might have AppArmor or SELinux

Comment: Please check how many `psql` client in your machine. Then, check `pidfile` param in `/etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message in the log was a red herring, and due to the configuration for Unix sockets (when I only needed TCP). Disabling Unix sockets by setting the `unix_socket_dir` to an empty string ([as per the documentation](https://pgbouncer.github.io/config.html)) made those errors disappear from the logs.

The connection problem was because I needed to specify the password in the pgbouncer.ini file.

The line:

```
* = host=myremoteIP port=5432 user=postgres
```

Needed to be:

```
* = host=myremoteIP port=5432 user=postgres password=mypassword
```

I can now connect using psql.

Comment: This is great for you, but I want to set up UNIX sockets, so in my case the error message is an issue, and I am still searching for an answer of how to get this working.